# Declaring a Table Variable - 1 row affected error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to DECLARE a table in my code so I can link up the necessary information. Simplified, I have this so far:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
      ID            INT
    , Name          VARCHAR(50)
    , Group         VARCHAR(50)
);

    INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Name,Group) VALUES (1234,'Name1','Group1')
    INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Name,Group) VALUES (5678,'Name2','Group2')
    INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Name,Group) VALUES (1910,'Name3','Group3')

SELECT O.ID,T.Name
FROM Order O WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN @Table T
        ON O.ID=A.ID
WHERE (O.Date >= '2013-10-01'
    AND O.Date < '2013-11-01')
GROUP BY O.ID,T.Name
ORDER BY O.ID
```

I'm trying to pull the Order table's ID where the dates match my specified range, and match those results with the related 'Name' from my declared table variable.

Whenever I run the code, I get:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

...listed many times (maybe one per each INSERT line in my code). Any ideas or glaring errors in my code?

Comment: I think that ON `O.ID=A.ID` must be `ON O.ID=T.ID`.

Comment: Oh thanks. That was just a typo. I changed the real names to temp ones for this question and forgot to switch that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(1 row(s) affected)` is a standard message you get from SQL Server whenever you modify rows.

If you don't want those messages, you can use `SET NOCOUNT ON` but they certainly aren't an indicator of anything wrong.

You might want to use a [table value constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) in order to insert the rows in a larger batch, however.

Comment: omg I was in the wrong tab. I guess I haven't woken up yet. Thanks so much for the suggestions though! I will look into that.

Comment: Whoa, except now it says
`Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 2652
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 3763
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.`

but I haven't changed anything.

Comment: @spazzie - That's because one of your values is longer than 50 characters long.